# Access a directive variable in a component template

Tags: angular, directive

I have this Directive =>

```
export class ThrottleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() 
    throttleTime = 500;

    @Output() 
    throttleClick = new EventEmitter();

    public throttling = false;
    private clicks = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
            throttleTime(this.throttleTime)
        ).subscribe(e => {
            this.throttleClick.emit(e)
            this.throttling = false;   
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.clicks.next(event);
        this.throttling = true;
    }
}
```

and this is my template

```
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
        [ngClass]="[((button.className) ? button.className : ''), 'custom-popup-button']" 
        [disabled]="(button.type === 'confirmation')"
        appThrottleClick 
        (throttleClick)="button.action();" 
        [throttleTime]="500">
        {{button.text}}
    </button>
```

I would like to disable my button IF the but `throttling` is currently true (so that it shows the click is been accounted for.

Is there a way to access that variable from the template (outside the directive)

this component (the component where the button come from) is a generic component that as a different amount of button base on the setup, so I can't really store variable on it. The best way would be to have some kind of connection between the `disable` and the `throttling`

Comment: You can disable button from directive using "HostBinding". Did you tried ?

Comment: no never heard of, I will look into it, sound like the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work

```
@HostBinding('class.myDisableClass') throttling:boolean;
```

and in css

```
.myDisableClass button{
   cursor: not-allowed;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to change the class, I changed only the attribute disabled. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I see it now. My bad. This is a directive that works directly on the button. I misread it and thought it was a component with a button within. Sorry